# How to interpret the probabilities (p0, p1) of the result of h2o.predict()

Tags: r, machine-learning, deep-learning, h2o, glm

I would like to understand the meaning of the value (result) of [h2o.predict()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/h2o/versions/2.8.4.4/topics/h2o.predict) function from H2o R-package. I realized that in some cases when the `predict` column is `1`, the `p1` column has a lower value than the column `p0`. My interpretation of `p0` and `p1` columns refer to the probabilities for each event, so I expected when `predict=1` the probability of `p1` should be higher than the probability of the opposite event (`p0`), but it doesn't occur always as I can show in the following example: using [prostate dataset](https://h2o-public-test-data.s3.amazonaws.com/smalldata/prostate/prostate.csv).

Here is executable example:

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init(max_mem_size = "12g", nthreads = -1)
prostate.hex <- h2o.importFile("https://h2o-public-test-data.s3.amazonaws.com/smalldata/prostate/prostate.csv")
prostate.hex$CAPSULE  <- as.factor(prostate.hex$CAPSULE)
prostate.hex$RACE     <- as.factor(prostate.hex$RACE)
prostate.hex$DCAPS    <- as.factor(prostate.hex$DCAPS)
prostate.hex$DPROS    <- as.factor(prostate.hex$DPROS)

prostate.hex.split = h2o.splitFrame(data = prostate.hex,
  ratios = c(0.70, 0.20, 0.10), seed = 1234)
train.hex     <- prostate.hex.split[[1]]
validate.hex  <- prostate.hex.split[[2]]
test.hex      <- prostate.hex.split[[3]]

fit <- h2o.glm(y = "CAPSULE", x = c("AGE", "RACE", "PSA", "DCAPS"),
  training_frame = train.hex,
  validation_frame = validate.hex,
  family = "binomial", nfolds = 0, alpha = 0.5)

prostate.predict = h2o.predict(object = fit, newdata = test.hex)
result <- as.data.frame(prostate.predict)
subset(result, predict == 1 & p1 < 0.4)
```

I get the following output for the result of the `subset` function:

```
   predict        p0        p1
11       1 0.6355974 0.3644026
17       1 0.6153021 0.3846979
23       1 0.6289063 0.3710937
25       1 0.6007919 0.3992081
31       1 0.6239587 0.3760413
```

For all the above observations from `test.hex` dataset the prediction is `1`, but `p0 > p1`.

The total observation where `predict=1` but `p1 < p0` is:

```
>   nrow(subset(result, predict == 1 & p1 < p0))
[1] 14
```

On contrary there are no `predict=0` where `p0 < p1`

```
>   nrow(subset(result, predict == 0 & p0 < p1))
[1] 0
```

Here is the table for `table` information for `predict`:

```
> table(result$predict)

 0  1 
18 23
```

We are using as a decision variable `CAPSULE` with the following values:

```
> levels(as.data.frame(prostate.hex)$CAPSULE)
[1] "0" "1"
```

Any suggestion?

**Note**: The question with a similar topic: [How to interpret results of h2o.predict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41075416/how-to-interpret-results-of-h2o-predict) does not address this specific issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems (also see [here](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-tutorials/blob/master/tutorials/glm/glm.md)) that the threshold that maximizes the `F1 score` on the `validation` dataset is used as the default threshold for classification with `h2o.glm()`.  We can observe the following:

1. the threshold value that maximizes `F1 score` on the validation dataset is `0.363477`.
2. all datapoints with predicted `p1` probability less than this threshold value are classified as `0` class (a datapoint predicted to be a `0` class has the highest `p1` probability = `0.3602365` < `0.363477`).
3. all datapoints with predicted `p1` probability greater than this threshold value are classified as `1` class (a datapoint predicted to be a `1` class has the lowest `p1` probability = `0.3644026` > `0.363477`).

   ```
   min(result[result$predict==1,]$p1)
   # [1] 0.3644026
   max(result[result$predict==0,]$p1)
   # [1] 0.3602365

   # Thresholds found by maximizing the metrics on the training dataset
   fit@model$training_metrics@metrics$max_criteria_and_metric_scores 
   #Maximum Metrics: Maximum metrics at their respective thresholds
   #                        metric threshold    value idx
   #1                       max f1  0.314699 0.641975 200
   #2                       max f2  0.215203 0.795148 262
   #3                 max f0point5  0.451965 0.669856  74
   #4                 max accuracy  0.451965 0.707581  74
   #5                max precision  0.998285 1.000000   0
   #6                   max recall  0.215203 1.000000 262
   #7              max specificity  0.998285 1.000000   0
   #8             max absolute_mcc  0.451965 0.395147  74
   #9   max min_per_class_accuracy  0.360174 0.652542 127
   #10 max mean_per_class_accuracy  0.391279 0.683269  97

   # Thresholds found by maximizing the metrics on the validation dataset
   fit@model$validation_metrics@metrics$max_criteria_and_metric_scores 
   #Maximum Metrics: Maximum metrics at their respective thresholds
   #                        metric threshold    value idx
   #1                       max f1  0.363477 0.607143  33
   #2                       max f2  0.292342 0.785714  51
   #3                 max f0point5  0.643382 0.725806   9
   #4                 max accuracy  0.643382 0.774194   9
   #5                max precision  0.985308 1.000000   0
   #6                   max recall  0.292342 1.000000  51
   #7              max specificity  0.985308 1.000000   0
   #8             max absolute_mcc  0.643382 0.499659   9
   #9   max min_per_class_accuracy  0.379602 0.650000  28
   #10 max mean_per_class_accuracy  0.618286 0.702273  11

   result[order(result$predict),]
   #   predict          p0        p1
   #5        0 0.703274569 0.2967254
   #6        0 0.639763460 0.3602365
   #13       0 0.689557497 0.3104425
   #14       0 0.656764541 0.3432355
   #15       0 0.696248328 0.3037517
   #16       0 0.707069611 0.2929304
   #18       0 0.692137408 0.3078626
   #19       0 0.701482762 0.2985172
   #20       0 0.705973644 0.2940264
   #21       0 0.701156961 0.2988430
   #22       0 0.671778898 0.3282211
   #24       0 0.646735016 0.3532650
   #26       0 0.646582708 0.3534173
   #27       0 0.690402957 0.3095970
   #32       0 0.649945017 0.3500550
   #37       0 0.804937468 0.1950625
   #40       0 0.717706731 0.2822933
   #41       0 0.642094040 0.3579060
   #1        1 0.364577068 0.6354229
   #2        1 0.503432724 0.4965673
   #3        1 0.406771233 0.5932288
   #4        1 0.551801718 0.4481983
   #7        1 0.339600779 0.6603992
   #8        1 0.002978593 0.9970214
   #9        1 0.378034417 0.6219656
   #10       1 0.596298925 0.4037011
   #11       1 0.635597359 0.3644026
   #12       1 0.552662241 0.4473378
   #17       1 0.615302107 0.3846979
   #23       1 0.628906297 0.3710937
   #25       1 0.600791894 0.3992081
   #28       1 0.216571552 0.7834284
   #29       1 0.559174924 0.4408251
   #30       1 0.489514642 0.5104854
   #31       1 0.623958696 0.3760413
   #33       1 0.504691497 0.4953085
   #34       1 0.582509462 0.4174905
   #35       1 0.504136056 0.4958639
   #36       1 0.463076505 0.5369235
   #38       1 0.510908093 0.4890919
   #39       1 0.469376828 0.5306232
   ```

Comment: This answer and the one provided by @DarrenCook are a valid response to my question. I will mark this solution as the best one because it gives also a numerical explanation based on the specific problem I posted. Both are really very valuable responses.

Answer (score 6):

What you are describing is a threshold of 0.5. In fact a different threshold will be used, one that maximizes a certain metric. The default metric is F1 (*); if you print the model information you can find the thresholds used for each metric.

See the question: [How to understand the metrics of H2OModelMetrics Object through h2o.performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43700476/841830) for more on this (your question was different, which was why I didn't mark it as a duplicate).

As far as I know you cannot change the F1 default to either `h2o.predict()` or `h2o.performance()`. But instead you can use `h2o.confusionMatrix()`

Given your model `fit`, and to use max F2 instead:

```
h2o.confusionMatrix(fit, metrics = "f2")
```

You can also just use the `h2o.predict()` "p0" column directly, with your own threshold, instead of the "predict" column. (That is what I have done, before.)

*: The definition is here: https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/fdde85e41bad5f31b6b841b300ce23cfb2d8c0b0/h2o-core/src/main/java/hex/AUC2.java#L34  Further down that file also shows how each of the metrics is calculated.

Comment: based on the @SandipanDey response it seems the be the metric: `max f1` and not the `max f0point5` for this case. There is no so much documentation for `h2o.predict()`. Can you provide some hint or link about to specify for prediction function a different performance metric? I have an imbalance class, so rather than `max f1` I guess it would be more convenient to use `max f2` that penalizes more the FN. I guess If have to specify some parameter using via `...` input argument.

Comment: @DavidLeal I updated my answer (re. F1) before your comment, but you probably already had it open and didn't see. Use `h2o.confusionMatrix` to specify your own threshold.