# h20 predict function probability scoring on test data

Tags: machine-learning, h2o, predictive, h2o4gpu

I have created h20 random forest model for fraud prediction.now while scoring using predict function  for test data. I got below dataframe from predict function output.

Now for 2nd records it predicted 1 but probability of p1 is far less than p0. What's the correct probability scores (p0/1) and classification we can use for my fraud prediction model?

If these are not correct probabilities then calibrated probabilities calculated using parameters(calibrate_model = True) as mentioned below will give correct probability?

```
    nfolds=5
    rf1 = h2o.estimators.H2ORandomForestEstimator(
        model_id = "rf_df1", 
        ntrees = 200,
        max_depth = 4,
        sample_rate = .30,
       # stopping_metric="misclassification",
       # stopping_rounds = 2, 
        mtries = 6,
        min_rows = 12,
        nfolds=3,
        distribution = "multinomial",
        fold_assignment="Modulo",
        keep_cross_validation_predictions=True,
        calibrate_model = True,
        calibration_frame = calib,
        weights_column = "weight",
        balance_classes = True
      #  stopping_tolerance = .005)
       )

        predict p0          p1
    1   0   0.9986012   0.000896514
    2   1   0.9985695   0.000448676
    3   0   0.9981387   0.000477767
```

Answer (score 0):

The prediction labels are based on a threshold and the threshold used is generally based on the threshold that maximizes the F1 score. See the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52304696/how-to-interpret-the-probabilities-p0-p1-of-the-result-of-h2o-predict/52309295#52309295) to learn more on how to interpret the probability results.

Details on how the calibration frame and model work can be found [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/calibrate_model.html?highlight=calibration) and [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/calibration_frame.html?highlight=calibration).